# update not working using vuejs3 and json it gives empty for the course fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm new to `vuejs 3` and `json`, i want to update a course, but it doesn't work, it is empty for all the course fields `{title and content}`, it gives me no error.
in `views / blog / OnePost` I declare the id of a course that I want updated, as a `props`

**views/blog/Edit.vue**

```
<template lang="">

    <div class="row my-4">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
            <h1 class="my-2">New Post</h1>
            <form @submit.prevent="editPost">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Title">Title</label>
                    <input v-model="post.title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Content">Content</label>
                    <textarea v-model="post.content" id="content" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-warning">update</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['id'],
     data() {
        return{
         url: `http://localhost:5000/posts/${this.id}`,
            post : {
                title:   '',
                content: ''
            }
        }
     },
     methods: {
         editPost() {
             if(this.post.title == '' || this.post.content == ''){
                 return;
             }
             
            fetch(this.url, {
                method: 'PUT',
                hearders: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(this.post)
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.$router.push('/blog'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
         }

     },
      mounted() {
       
            fetch(this.url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.post = data
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        
    }
    
}
</script>
```

**views/blog/OnePost.vue**

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'post-edit', params: { id: post.id }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning ml-3">edit</router-link>
```

Comment: You have a typo `hearders` should be `headers`. Also your update button should have a `type="submit"`. Please provide more information about what is happening.

Comment: @RoboKozo thx its working

Comment: Ok I'll submit it as an answer so you can mark the question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few issues with your code sample.

First, there is a typo: `hearders` should be `headers`

and second, your button element should have the `type="submit"`. The reason for this is you are using the form element. To trigger the form's associated `@submit` handler, a button within form must have the correct submit type.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form